# Convert string to negative number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to convert from string type to a number

```
list = ["-5","4","-3","variable"]  # Input

list = [-5,4,-3,"variable"]        # epected output
```

I have a problem when converting the negative number

```
list[0]=int(list[0])
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-5'

Comment: As far as I know, this code work perfectly fine in python 3.5.

Comment: `import re; list = map(lambda x:  -int(re.search('[\d]+', x).group() if '-' in x else int(x), list)`

Comment: I've had a similar error: for me had split a list on spaces, this left the commas attached to the digits

Answer (score 9):

Actually, I cannot reproduce your error , it just work in python 2.7.13

```
>>>int("-5")
>>> -5
```

and in python 3.4

so, it could be a python version problem , 
I recommend updating your python version , by reinstalling the newer , from the [site](http://www.python.org) , it will replace it perfectly ( packages untouched ) , unless you are using , a special distribution like anaconda ..

for processing your list ( mixed chars and numbers ) use:

`try: except:` 
 statement.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this problem in the matplotlib xticklabels Text attribute. The minus signs for negative numbers are encoded as a "minus":

> [−] is a minus (Unicode 2212).
>
> Minus: [&minus]; a.k.a. [&#8722]; a.k.a. [&#x2212];
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes

Python seems to code minuses as 'hyphen-minus', Unicode 002D:

> [-] is a hyphen-minus (ASCII keyboard, Unicode 002D)
>
> Hyphen minus: [&#45]; a.k.a. [&#x002D];

Here is an example:

```
>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>> import re
>> x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>> y = [0,1,2,1,2,1]

>> fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
>> plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image: Scatter plot of toy data]
    .

If we try to get at the xticklabels, if we want to manually edit them, we use:

```
>> l = ax.get_xticklabels()
>> ticks = [i.get_text() for i in l]
>> print(ticks)

['−1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

>> ord(ticks[0])

8722
```

Try to convert it to an integer:

```
>> l = ax.get_xticklabels()
>> ticks = [int(i.get_text()) for i in l]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '−1'
```

This is the same error as in the question, which was difficult for others to recreate.
To fix it, use regular expressions:

```
ticks = [int(re.sub(u"\u2212", "-", i.get_text())) for i in l]
print(ticks)
print(ticks[0] - 1)

[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
-2

>> ord(ticks[0])

45
```

Comment: I got the same problem. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use a regex to check if an element is a number. This is my example:

```py
from re import match

list = ["-5", "4", "-3", "variable"]

print([int(x) if match(r'^-?[0-9]+$', x) else x for x in list])
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to replace values in a list, you will have to find that out for yourself. This code here

```
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #to make sure there are no letters in the string
list = ["-5","4","-3","variable"]
def MightWork(list):
    newlist = []
    for item in list:
        if set(abc) & set(list[item]) = False:
            newlist.append(int(list[item]))
return newlist

list = MightWork(list)
```

might work. The reason why your code did not work is because you were changing the entire list into a string, not each individual item in the list. Knowing this, if you have any better solutions, try them.

Answer (score 0):

code you written above is working fine in python3

```
list1 = ["-5","4","-3","variable"]
list2 = []
print(list1)
for item in list1:
    try:
        list2.append(int(item))
    except ValueError as e:
        list2.append(item)
print(list2)
```

Output

```
['-5', '4', '-3', 'variable']
[-5, 4, -3, 'variable']
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this example.

```
list=[-1,2,'car']
convert=[]
for i in list.split():
    if type(i) == str:
        try:
            convert.append(type(map(int,i)))
        except ValueError:
            convert.append(type(i))
    return convert
```